# How to prevent a View from getting resized?

Tags: android

In my Android app, I display a view inside a RelativeLayout. This view is displayed closer to the bottom of the screen.

Things work fine until I click on an EditText control. This causes the virtual keyboard to pop up. As a result, the height of the RelativeLayout reduces (I think) forcing a change in the height of my view.

I am wondering if there is a way to prevent a view from getting resized. If not, perhaps something else could be done to maintain the aspect ratio. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" in manifest.

Answer (score 0):

The functionality windowSoftInputMode will either pan or resize your activity layout.

Just add this property in the manifest when declaring your activity:

> android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

or

> android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

to push your Views...

Hope this helps!

Regards!